# Applescript return value of do script

Tags: applescript

I'm having a problem with the types when getting a getting a return value back from a do shell script.

I'm checking if there are still running unix processes of rsync

```
repeat until (do shell script "/bin/ps -ef  | /usr/bin/grep -c [r]sync") > 0
        delay 120
end repeat
tell application "Terminal" to quit
```

The value thats coming back is correct: --> "4" but the script goes direct to the quit.
I don't know how to set the right types, I have already tried:

```
repeat until (do shell script "/bin/ps -ef  | /usr/bin/grep -c [r]sync") > "0"
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "the script goes direct to the quit"? What are you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: If there are still rsync processes running the script may not exit the Terminal app. That why I uses the > 0

Comment: I get it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misinterpreted the behavior of `repeat until`: The loop is repeated as long as the condition is **not** true. As you already have running processes, your condition will yield true and thus, the inner part (`delay 120`) won't be executed.

What you want is to repeat the loop as long as there are running processes. So you need to compare with `= 0` instead of `> 0`.

So you can either write:

```
repeat until (do shell script "/bin/ps -ef  | /usr/bin/grep -c [r]sync") = "0"
```

or you can stick with your condition and use a `while` loop that expresses a "as long as" condition:

```
repeat while (do shell script "/bin/ps -ef  | /usr/bin/grep -c [r]sync") > "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have that condition set the way you want it? Your logic is to repeat *until* the result is greater than 0. But if the result is greater than zero, then there are still sync processes running. For example, you say that the result is sometimes 4. When the result is 4, this simplifies to:

```
repeat until 4 > 0
    delay 120
end repeat
tell application "Terminal" to quit
```

Since 4 is greater than 0, the condition has been met: it will no longer repeat, since it is only repeating until the value is greater than zero, which it is. Thus, it falls through to the next step, which is to tell the Terminal to quit.

I think you want either a repeat while value > 0, or a repeat until value = 0.

Comment: For me the the logic was, If 4 > 0 (still a proccess running) the script may not quit the terminal and should delay. I'll try the  = 0 solution

Comment: Sure. The difference between *until* and *while* is that “repeat until” repeats *until* that condition is met; that is, once the condition is met, it stops repeating and continues on after “end repeat”. Whereas, “repeat while” repeats *while* that condition is met; that is, the repeat loop is exited only once the condition is *not* met. Since you have the until variant, and 4 is greater than 0, the condition is met and the loop is never even entered. Note that if the script ever started when there was no process running, it would enter into a nearly endless loop: 0 is not greater than 0.